# Find words only containing given characters : RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I have set of words. For example,

```
abc, adb, acb, cab, abcc, abk, bacc
```

I want to find words which only have

> abc

so, result I need is

```
abc, acb, cab, abcc, bacc
```

I need to find this using Regular Expressions.

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Does the word `a` constitute a match?

Comment: Hey, just a thought: maybe you should [read up on regex a little](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) before asking for help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex below will find all your words only with abc characters inside them.

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\b[abc]+\\b");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    // matched text: regexMatcher.group()
    // match start: regexMatcher.start()
    // match end: regexMatcher.end()
}
```

Comment: sorry for disturb you, but is there any other way to find this kind of strings rather than using RegEx? Any algorithm which can use for this.

Comment: Well if your input is a list with , you could use the split method put them in an array of words and then check each element of the array against a group of characters that you want to have/not have.

Comment: That's good way to do it, but I have some big performance problems. I've found Boyer-Moore string search algorithm and some few algorithms but I wasn't able to use them for this matter.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm Even has an implementation in C. Why weren't you able to use them?

Answer (score 3):

Not worrying about case for a simple example

[a-c]+

will match any combination of one-or-more letters from a-c

[afz]+

would do the same for a,f,z

As well as considering case, you'd also want to consider what constitues a 'word' (preceded and succeeded by whitespace or whatever)?

Comment: Java regexps support `\b` to match a word boundary. (Where "word" means "whatever `\w` matches", presumably.)

Comment: This will match abcbla blacbla etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
\\b[abc]+\\b
```

or

```
\\b[a-c]+\\b
```

`[` and `]` denotes a [character set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), and `+` means 1 or more [repetitions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of any character within the set. `\b` is [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), so you will only match full words.

[Example.](http://ideone.com/pWFlf)

Comment: This will also match "fooabc" or "whatever"

Comment: @FailedDev aye, I was in the process of editing, forgot that.